# Differentiable function with differentiable inverse must be continuously differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity, examples-counterexamples

I was wondering, if there is a function $f$ that is differentiable everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$ (but **not continuously differentiable**), with a *differentiable inverse*.

Since it needs to be bijective and it is continuous, it is w.l.o.g. strictly increasing and thus has nonnegative derivative everywhere.

I have tried looking at the standard pathological functions that I know of, but I couldn‘t find any example.

If the restriction to invertible functions with differentiable inverse wasn’t there, then there are some good examples of such pathological functions.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for you very much for your great answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The derivative of an differentiable function with a (differentiable) inverse function is not necessarily continuous.

The function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined as
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
 4x + x^2 \sin(1/x) & \text{ if } x \ne 0 \, , \\
 0  & \text{ if } x = 0 \,,
\end{cases}
$$
is differentiable everywhere, with
$$
 f'(x) = \begin{cases}
 4 + 2x \sin(1/x) -\cos(1/x) & \text{ if } x \ne 0 \, , \\
 4  & \text{ if } x = 0 \, ,
\end{cases}
$$
but $f'$ is *not continuous* at $x=0$.

For all $x \ne 0$ is $|x \sin(1/x)| \le 1$ and $|\cos(1/x)| \le 1$, so that $f'(x) \ge 1$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$. It follows that $f$ is strictly increasing and therefore invertible. The inverse function is differentiable everywhere by the [inverse function rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_rule).